# How to merge the attributes of point shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, vector, merge, dissolve

I am trying to make wind map in QGIS, where I used vector point shapefile.

Because I have two different shapefiles I first merged them:

[image]

Then I Dissolve it where I choose two attributes to dissolved:

[image]

[image]

But it seemes that the attributes did not dissolve.

[image]

[image]

How can solve this?

Comment: How do you define merging of attributes? What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: Are the values of those two attributes equal for the overlapping features in both datasets?

Comment: I think that the problem it isn't when you disolve, it starts when you merge the shapefields.

I imagine that where there are two close arrows you want one. This happens because the correspondence of the points of the shapefiles is not perfect. In that case, look for a way to merge it by making the points correspond.

After that, I see that for the same point the arrows are different, you should recalculate the values ​​from those of the two arrows or take only one.... I would join the layers with "overlay fields prefix" and got the average between the two in a new field.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to "connect" the points where the two grids overlap: the points are probably not in the exact same location, but somehow shifted. So create a new point exactly in the middle of two neighboring points from the two grids, then combine the attributes from both layers.

Let's suppose your two grid layers are called `grid1` and `grid2`.

1. On layer `grid1`, select points that overlap the extent of `grid2`. Use Select by expression with this expression:

```
    within (
        $geometry, 
        layer_property( 
            'grid2', 
            'extent'
        )
    )
```

2. Use `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Geoemtry by expression`, use `grid1` as input, check `Selected features only` and insert this expression (replace `190` in line 7 with a distance a bit larger then the distance between neighboring points from the two grids):

```
    centroid (
        make_line (
            $geometry, 
            overlay_nearest (
                'grid2',
                $geometry,
                max_distance:=190
            )[0]
        )
    )
```

3. On this new point layer, use Field calculator to get any attribute (here: `value2`) from `grid2` with this expression:

```
    overlay_nearest (
        'grid2',
        "value2"
    )[0]
```

4. Aggregate the values from the two layers - like sum, mean etc., whatever you need. Use field calculator for this.
5. You have now a new point layer that combines the points from both grids where they overlap. In the original grids, delete the points where the extent of the two grids overlap - use the expression from step 1 to select the points to be deleted.
6. Now you can merge the three layers: remaining points from `grid1`, remaining points from `grid2` and the points from the layer created in step 2.

*Red points: grid1, blue points: grid2; orange points created in step 2:*
[image]